# Count selected checkboxes without event (Angular)

Tags: angular, checkbox

Is it possible to count selected checkboxes without firing an event?

I have a dynamic list of items and want to show the user the total number selected, live.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="form-check">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="itemCheck{{i}}" name="item{{i}}"[(ngModel)]="item.checked" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="itemCheck{{i}}">{{item.Name}}</label>
</div>

{{item.checked.length}}
```

The answers I've seen have been event based.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to use events?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want Angular to notice the change of the state of an input type checkbox, you either can use events or poll for changes, e.g. check every 500ms if there have been any changes in the selection state of input type checkboxes, though it is not recommended to poll. The event based pattern is the recommended one. Why can't you use events?

Comment: I'd want to filter occasionally than track through an event continually

Comment: What do you mean with occasionally? After a click? After a route change? After e.g. 500ms? Please specify

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason you can't use events at all, you'll need to automatically update your information at an interval:

```
public selectedCount = 0;
public ngOnInit() {
    interval(500) // time in ms
    .subscribe(() => this.setItemCount);
}

public setItemCount() {
    this.selectedCount = this.items.length;
}
```

This will update the count every 500ms.

You can of course call setItemCount whenever else you want - e.g. when an event has been fired.

Answer (score 0):

If any value changes the lifecyclehook ngDocheck runs and we can make change detection by comparing the previous and new value

In Component

```
ngDoCheck(){
    let count = this.items.filter(i=>i.checked).length
    if(count != this.length){
      this.length=count
    }
  }
```

In html

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]="name" name='name' />
{{name}}
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="form-check">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="itemCheck{{i}}" name="item{{i}}"[(ngModel)]="item.checked" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="itemCheck{{i}}">{{item.Name}}</label>
</div>

{{length}}
```

please refer this [stackblitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttwwdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)